# Convert a decimal value in system.drawing.point

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have two variables declared as decimal

```
Dim datok As Decimal
Dim datol As Decimal
```

both were filled with values from rs232 port and Ineed to draw a line with these points, but when I try to pass the values of datok and datol to a point structure the error "Value of type 'Decimal' cannot be converted to 'system.drawing.point'
How I can convert the value decimal of datok in a system.drawing.point
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`PointF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.PointF%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Structure.

From above link:

> Represents an ordered pair of floating-point x- and y-coordinates that defines a point in a two-dimensional plane.

i.e.

```
Dim datok As Decimal
Dim datol As Decimal

Dim myPoint As PointF = New PointF(datok, datol)
```

I am not sure how you are drawing your lines, but there are corresponding Graphics Methods the use the `PointF` Structure instead of `Point` as in this [`DrawLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/021a23yy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method

Or if you are content to have some data loss you can just convert the decimals to integers when you create your `Point`

i.e.

```
Dim myPoint As Point = New Point(CInt(datok), CInt(datol))
```